# Swift dynamic table cell height

Tags: ios, uitableview, height, ios-autolayout

I have tableview with prototype cell, 
in the cell I have imageview and some text under. 
The text label is one laine in the prototype cell, but sometimes it is more than one line, I'm loading the data to the table view after server call.
The label in storyboard Lines are set to 0 and Line Break to Word Wrap. 
I also tried http://candycode.io/automatically-resizing-uitableviewcells-with-dynamic-text-height-using-auto-layout/

but no effect. 
If I use [Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights)
everything works because the label text is predefined, but I'm loading the data from server and I reload the tableView after the API call, and then the label is just one line.

Comment: Does your label have bottom constraint to tableViewCell?

Comment: yes, I use suggested constraints, should I remove it?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36437861/what-constraints-would-prevent-my-uiviews-from-stacking-on-top-of-each-other/36438009#36438009

Comment: it is not duplicate, because this works if I have the data, but I'm loading the data after the tableview was created and then call reloadData()

Comment: No don't remove it...Try following the answer to the link suggested by @Scriptable

Comment: Can you share the screenshot and code or if possible share the project

Comment: The problem was in My constraints, cleared them all and added them manually, and in viewDidLoad used 

self.tableView.setNeedsLayout()
self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()

Answer (score 55):

You should use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` provides a solution for displaying dynamic content.

Use below code in `viewDidLoad`:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = YourTableViewCellHeight
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
```

[Read more from here](http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/)

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: This works with autolayout!
I add also that "tableView.estimatedRowHeight = xxx " is needed in order to make it work, it's not optional.

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/1067-self-sizing-table-view-cells

Answer (score 26):

make sure UILabel height constraint not to be constant, if constant it have to set Relation **greater than or equal to**  from attribute inspector

make sure  UITableViewestimate row height set as per your.

```
   tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 85
```

and write in `UITableViewCell` class

```
 cell.lbl_name.sizeToFit()
 cell.lbl_name.numberOfLines = 0
```

Make sure your `UITableViewDelegate` method

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```