# Table View Cell Row Height doesnt work

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, row-height

[image]

I have tried to hard code the row height in the table view cell. After running the program it looks like only one line. I suspect it is because of the height of the row of the table view.

Could you please tell me what went wrong in here?

Comment: no issue seems with height, have you also set height from delegate method in code? If so remove that method.

Comment: what is your label line number? it should be 0 and what about your constraint set ? would you share with that on the other hand did you set for dynamic constraint table view height?

Comment: You can check my answer hope this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/36574334/1776470

Answer (score 53):

In **Xcode 9**, `tableview` automatically create estimated cells based on `Autolayout`. Since you have not provide autolayout, that's why you are getting this.

You need to disable estimated and automatic cell size by selecting tableview and uncheck the two options:

[image]

Give value you want to Row height, and cell will be created accordingly.

Hope this can help.

Comment: What can I do if I have different kind of prototype cells with different heights?

Answer (score 9):

Add this code in your UITableViewDelegate

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}
```

Comment: No, do not do this. If all rows have the same height it is better to simply set the table view's `rowHeight` property once in `viewDidLoad`. Only implement this delegate method if different rows have different heights.

Comment: @rmaddy As per apple doc, delegate have better performance then property.

Comment: @dahiya_boy You misread the documentation. The documentation for `UITableView rowHeight` and `UITableViewDelegate heightForRowAt` clearly state that the delegate method is a performance issue. It is far more efficient to set the `rowHeight` property than use the delegate method assuming all rows have the same height.

Answer (score 3):

Ensure following steps to make, auto dimension effective for cell/row height layout. (Here is sample code for UILabel and how to set content specific height for table cell.)

- Assign and implement dataSource and delegate
- Assign `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` to rowHeight & estimatedRowHeight
- Implement delegate/dataSource methods (i.e. `heightForRowAt` and return a value `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` to it)

-

```
@IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Don't forget to set dataSource and delegate for table
    table.dataSource = self
    table.delegate = self

    // Set automatic dimensions for row height
    // Swift 4.2 onwards
    table.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    table.estimatedRowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension


    // Swift 4.1 and below
    table.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    table.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

}



// UITableViewAutomaticDimension calculates height of label contents/text
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    // Swift 4.2 onwards
    return UITableView.automaticDimension

    // Swift 4.1 and below
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

For label instance in UITableviewCell

- Set number of lines = 0 (& line break mode = truncate tail)
- Set all constraints (top, bottom, right left) with respect to its superview/ cell container.
- *Optional*: Set minimum height for label, if you want minimum vertical area covered by label, even if there is no data.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Set row height as well as estimated row height as Automatic in `viewDidLoad()` as

```
table.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
table.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

In `heightForRowAt:` set height as `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` as

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Note: Set number of lines of label `long restaurant name` as 0.

Answer (score 3):

You can manually do it in your tableviewdelegate:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Set number of lines to 0
2. Set

```
   yourTableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension and 
   yourTableView.estimatedRowHeight =  UITableView.automaticDimension
```

3. return `UITableView.automaticDimension` in `tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)` delegate method
4. Set all constraints . Bottom constraint is important to increase table view cell height .

Your all set to go

Answer (score 0):

If you want the cells to occupy space according to its content, you need to return **UITableViewAutomaticDimension** in the table view delegate methods **heightForRowAt**: and **estimatedHeightForRowAt**:

Comment: you can also use: 
yourTable.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
yourTable.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Answer (score 0):

Following [this guide](https://www.raywenderlich.com/8549-self-sizing-table-view-cells) which worked for me, you have to add a bunch of constraints and then the rowheight is calculated automatically.

In short, what I did: (adding and modifying constraints are the two rightmost buttons bottom right of the storyboard view)I at first selected all views in the prototype cell, deleted all constraints (there is a nice option on the rightmost button), then added all missing constraints (another nice option there) and last I chose the second button from the right and clicked all the red lines. You can do this while having all views selected at the same time. And then it worked.