# How to set the tableview cell height Dynamically?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, heightforrowatindexpath

I'm working with `Tableview` in `Swift` Now I got an issue with tableview cell height .I'm working on the chat Screen so I have text, Image. so I took one prototype cell within that I'm managing the screen.
Now below is my Code for Height

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if msg_type == "Image"  {
        return 150
    }else if msg_type == "Text"{
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension

    }
}
```

so text cell not getting as I expected, But here I don't know where is my mistake, and one more thing if I `return UITableViewAutomaticDimension` it is working fine for Text messages, not images.
Please help me thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36574334/1776470

Comment: are you reloading your tableview???

Answer (score 0):

Make height dynamic like this

1- put this in viewDidLoad

```
     self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
     self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 150.0;
```

2- before return cell in cellForRow

```
    cell.layoutSubviews()

    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
```

3- hook constraints properly from top to bottom in cell xib or storyboard prototype

so , whether it's a cell containing a fixed height image like what you want 150 Or a multi line text it will be layouted properly

4- don't implement heightForRowAt

Comment: You don't need to call the layoutSubviews in cellForRow and would only need to cell layoutIfNeeded if it's required for something like an animation.

Comment: I do need as in complex layout cells the cell may encounter wrong height calculation , doing this solves the problem with me

Comment: Well for the layoutSubviews direct from the Apple documentation 'You should not call this method directly. If you want to force a layout update, call the setNeedsLayout() method instead to do so prior to the next drawing update. If you want to update the layout of your views immediately, call the layoutIfNeeded() method.'  So it you do need to call it directly you are doing something wrong.  The layoutIfNeeded is only required if you want the layout immediately for some other calculation.  Otherwise it is all handled automatically.

Comment: layoutSubviews redraws the object whether it needs layout or not , while layoutIfNeeded checks first , and as you may expect it's always there is a constraint configuration in cellForRow , so calling layoutSuvviews ensures completing the process and apending layoutIfNeeded  for any issue handling

Comment: layoutSubviews draws nothing it just calculates the layout.  It also does nothing unless you override it (straight from the Apple documentation). So unless you have overridden it then nothing happens.  You should call setNeedsLayout and then layoutIfNeeded it you want everything to be flagged for recalculation and then recalculated immediately.  It's probably not causing any harm calling it direct but I try to avoid going against what the documentation specifically says.

Comment: Hi @Sh_Khan as you said I did , still it is showing same...I mean what is the problem with heightForRowAt  it works fine in objective c.

Comment: you set constraints properly in cell xib from top to bottom ??

Comment: Thanks But not working ,I taken constraints as you said top to bottom

Comment: hooked bottom constraint of bottom most item to content view]