# How to set NSLayoutConstraint in Swift?

Tags: swift, constraints

I want to change some constraints aromatically in different cases.

Declaration of my Constraints coming from the storyboard:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var topConstraintPostImageView: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

This is my code, where I want to change the constraints:

```
func updateCellView(post: PostModel) {

    // Wenn Bild mit Text gepostet wird
    if post.imageURL != nil && post.postText != nil {

        topConstraintPostImageView.constant = 10

        // Wenn Text ohne bild gepostet wird
    } else if post.imageURL == nil && post.postText != nil  {

        heightConstraint.constant = 1

        // Wenn Bild ohne Text gepostet wird
    } else if post.imageURL != nil && post.postText == nil {

        topConstraintPostImageView.constant = 0

    }
}
```

But the constraints still doesn't change.

Here my cellForRowAt func:

```
    extension DiscoveryViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    // wie viele Zellen
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return postArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DiscoveryCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DiscoveryCollectionViewCell

        cell.updateCellView(post: postArray[indexPath.row].post!)
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        cell.user = postArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.post = postArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.delegate = self

        return cell
    }
}
```

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you sure that at least one condition is `true`?

Comment: Yes the code is more complex, but I simplified for this question. All datas will be loaded but not the constraints. Do I have to make special settings for the constraints in storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert in `cellForRowAt` in the vc

```
 cell.updateCellView(arr[indexPath.row])////  change arr to your datasource arr inside here set constants
 cell.layoutIfNeeded()
 return cell
```

at the end of the if statements

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Im inside a tableViewCell, Value of type 'DiscoveryTableViewCell' has no member 'view'´´

Comment: still the same problem but in the `VC``cellRowAt` 
`Value of type 'DiscoveryTableViewCell' has no member 'configure'`

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36574052/swift-dynamic-table-cell-height ,

Comment: screenshot the layout of the cell with constraints shown

Comment: every if need a separate else to give the reverse value of constant when the condition doesn't fit , ex if image url exists then constant height say = 20 and if no then zero , do this for all constraints , as cells are dequeued

Answer (score 0):

Consider calling `setNeedsUpdateConstraints()` on your view from `updateCellView()` and then implement:

```
class MyView: UIView {
  // ...
  override func updateConstraints() {
    super.updateConstraints()
    // This is where you update your constraints including the logic above.
  }
  // ...
}
```

✳️ Better still, consider using UIStackViews to arrange and individually hide or show views you want to show conditionally.